# Установка Yii2 через Composer

Tags: yii, composer

В Win-10 Composer установлен отдельно от Open Server. Вначале пробовал установить Yii2 командой
 $ composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2 2.0.12

Затем сменил версию с Php7 на Php5.6 и Apache-2.4 и ввел команды 
 $ composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.3.1" 
$ composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2 2.0.12

но теперь он требует какой-то скрытый токен. Погуглив немного запутался т.к. везде разные советы 
  [Здесь](https://php.ru/forum/threads/reshenie-nekotoryx-problem-s-composer.52966/) рекомендуют выполнить "minimum-stability": "dev", //разрешаем dev
"prefer-stable": true //говорим, что сначала нужно попробовать stable Только непонятно где это нужно сделать, если файла json нет и такой метод не самый лучший. [Здесь](https://toster.ru/q/95703) проверить наличие расширения командами ext-xsl $ composer show --platform | grep ext-x
$ composer show --platform | grep ext-xsl

```
user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 MINGW64 /d/sites/mm.lo
$ composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2 2.0.12
Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.12)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.12): Loading from cache
Created project in yii2
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable                                                                                                                 | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.8 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable                                                                                                                 | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable                                                                                                                 | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stabl                                                                                                                e -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.12 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stabl                                                                                                                e | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@sta                                                                                                                ble | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@sta                                                                                                                ble | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.11 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stabl                                                                                                                e | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.10 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stabl                                                                                                                e | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 ~2.0.6 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii                                                                                                                2[2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min                                                                                                                imum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more det                                                                                                                ails.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further commo                                                                                                                n problems.

user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 MINGW64 /d/sites/mm.lo
$ composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.3.1"
$Changed current directory to C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Composer
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing fxp/composer-asset-plugin (v1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 MINGW64 /d/sites/mm.lo
$ composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2 2.0.12
Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.12)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.12): Loading from cache
Created project in yii2
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading bower.json of bower-asset/jquery (1.11.3)
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery-dist/commits/1472290                                                                                                                 917f17af05e98007136096784f9051fab, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go ove                                                                                                                 r the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer                                                                                                                 +on+DESKTOP-OKASEM6+2017-06-16+2141
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Compos                                                                                                                 er/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
Token (hidden):
```

Comment: хочу написать игру на yii2 а заодно помогу разобраться я https://vk.com/des1roer

Answer (score 2):

Он же пишет по какому пути сходить (https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer ) и где с гитхаба его скопировать